# Isolate the country name from Location column

Tags: regex, pandas

I have data like this along with other columns in a pandas df.
Apologies I haven't figured out how to present the question with code for the dataframe. First Post

Location:
 - Tokyo, Japan 
 - Sacramento, USA
 - Mexico City, Mexico
 - Mexico City, Mexico
 - Colorado Springs, USA
 - New York, USA
 - Chicago, USA

Does anyone know how I could isolate the country name from the location and create a new column with just the Country Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [29]: pd.DataFrame(df.Location.str.split(',',1).tolist(), columns = ['City','Country'])
Out[29]: 
               City       Country
0             Tokyo         Japan
1        Sacramento           USA
2       Mexico City        Mexico
3       Mexico City        Mexico
4  Colorado Springs           USA
5             Seoul   South Korea
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any regular expressions - you can find the String.indexOf(“, “) to find the position of the seperator in the String, and then use String.substring to cut the String down to just this section.

However, a regular expression can also do this easily, but would likely be slower.